# How do I create a button that can change/restore a section's styling using onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick, toggle

Sorry total beginner.

I want to create a button with the onclick event attribute that can change the styling of all the elements within a section element with an id of "changeMe" with one click and change back to its original look with another click and vice versa.

Comment: Its ok that you are a begininner but atleast show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .colorRed{
      color:'red';
    }
    <style>


    </head>
    <body>
    <section id="section-to-toggle-style">
     <span> Test Text </span>
    </section>
    <button onCick="toggleStyle()">Toggle Style</button>

    </body>
<script> 
 var applied = false;
 function toggleStyle(){
 var sectionToModify = document.getElementById("section-to-toggle-style");
   if(!applied){
   sectionToModify.classList.add("colorRed");
   }else{

   sectionToModify.classList.remove("colorRed");
   }
 }
</script>
</html>
```

This code is not tested, but this should work well for your case, basic idea would be same. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the .css() function to change style of some part, and you can check whether your button was clicked before by manipulating a global boolean variable

Comment: should have mentioned that I want an answer purely javascript

Comment: Simply replace .css() with equivalent native functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a css class on and off for your section.

create a css class with styling you want. it will serve as the 'on'

dynamically add and remove it from/to your section to see it's effect going back to its original state -- which is without the class you created.